# Mod_rewrite rule doesent work

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite some url on my site

```
http://wwww.example.com/poem.php?s=to-sally
```

to

```
http://wwww.example.com/poems/to-sally
```

I wrote this rule but doesnt work

```
RewriteRule ^poems/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ poem.php?s=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

- Make sure you have RewirteEngine On, and actually have the mod_rewrite module loaded and running
- I believe the paths being matched against start with /, but your rule dictates that the first character is p.  Try replacing your match expression with `^/poems/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$` and see if that does the trick.